# Convert fractions into decimal (fractions are in superscript)

Tags: python

I am pulling text from a site and would like to convert the fractions into decimal.

The fractions are in subscript though and look like the following

1¼,4½

is it possible to get around this?

Comment: Those are distinct unicode characters. You could easily map `{'¼': Decimal('0.25')}` and add the numbers together with a bit of string parsing.

Comment: You should have a look at: http://www.econlib.org/library/asciicodes.html

Comment: You can check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Forms) for complete list of unicode number forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict = {
    '¼':0.25,
    '½':0.50,
}

def Convert(line):
    return [int(word[:-1])+dict[word[-1]] if word[-1] in dict else int(word) for word in line.split(',')]
```

If you have any other such symbols, then simply add them to `dict`.

Comment: If you have cases like `'¼'` (i.e., with no integer number next to the fraction), then this script will fail... So you might have to do a bit of improvement, but I trust that it puts you on the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Building on @barak manos' idea, i would just go and look for all my dictionary keys in every line and replace them on site like so:

```
dict = {
    '¼': '.25',
    '½': '.50',
}    

def convert(line, dict):
    for x in dict:
        line = line.replace(x, dict[x])
        line = line.replace(' ' + dict[x], ' 0' + dict[x])
    return line

a = '1¼ ½ 564as 25½'
print(convert(a,dict)) # returns: '1.25 0.50 564as 25.50'
```

The position of the characters you are looking for in the sentence and/or the presence of integers around them or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I think that generally this is a better idea than mine (it was also suggested in a comment by @deceze, BTW). But in your implementation, I'm pretty sure that you'll get (for example) `1¼` changed into `10.25`. Have you actually verified that it works?

Comment: @barakmanos very true. But i don't remember seeing a superscript alone so i will just change the dict values to ``.25`` and ``.50``. Orphan ``.25`` entries can also be searched and replaced by ``line.replace(' '+str(x), '0'+str(x))``

Answer (score -1):

You must parse these numbers out from text (depends encoding), use example some parser combinator or similar. Then you can calculate decimals.